# Mockito Argument Matcher any() - Argument(s) are different! for verify method called with any()

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockito, verify, argument-matcher

I am trying to write a test where I am very simply checking if a method was called on a mock. Should be easy, I've done it many times using verify, however for some reason my test is failing because it seems to be comparing the actual invocation arguments to `<any Type>`.

My code:

```
val mockSearchApi = mock<SearchApi>()
whenever(mockSearchApi.searchBrands(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any()))
     .thenReturn(Single.just(getSearchApiResponse()))

// Some code that causes the api .searchBrands to get called

verify(mockSearchApi, times(1)).searchBrands(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())
```

Then the test fails with error

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
searchApi.searchBrands(
    <any java.lang.Boolean>,
    <any java.util.List>,
    <any java.lang.Integer>,
    <any java.lang.Integer>,
    <any java.lang.String>,
    <any java.lang.String>,
    <any java.lang.Boolean>,
    <any java.util.Map>
);
-> at ...
Actual invocations have different arguments:
searchApi.searchBrands(
    false,
    [],
    1,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    true,
    {}
);
```

So the method is called and the argument types are correct, so why does this fail?

And I have also tried changing all of those any() calls to anyBoolean(), anyList(), anyString(), etc. and the same happens.
I have also ensured that the code is calling the arguments in the right order as I've seen that issue before with mocks as well.

Comment: Your `any()` comes form mockito-kotlin, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you used `any()` from mockito-kotlin

Original `ArgumentMatchers` behaviour:

- `any()` - Matches anything, including nulls and varargs.
- `any​(Class<T> type)` - Matches any object of given type, excluding nulls.
- both functions return null

To prevent exception when `null` is returned, mockito-kotlin changes this behaviour. See [Matchers.kt](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/blob/main/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/org/mockito/kotlin/Matchers.kt)

```kotlin
/** Matches any object, excluding nulls. */
inline fun <reified T : Any> any(): T {
    return ArgumentMatchers.any(T::class.java) ?: createInstance()
}

/** Matches anything, including nulls. */
inline fun <reified T : Any> anyOrNull(): T {
    return ArgumentMatchers.any<T>() ?: createInstance()
}
```

mockito-kotlin matchers behaviour:

- `any()` delegates to `ArgumentMatchers.any(T::class.java)` and thus does not match nulls
- `anyOrNull()` delegates to `ArgumentMatchers.any<T>()`  and thus matches null

Comment: ughhh thank you, I wasted a lot of time on this and `anyOrNull()` fixes it